# Plot data file `graficas.tkzfonct.table` not found

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, gnuplot, tkz-fct

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{tikz} % no need !
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\usepackage[left=1.1cm,right=1.1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.3cm]{geometry}
\author{Segundo H. Chiroque Reyes}
\title{Gráfica de funciones}
\date{}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{miproblema}{\fbox{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{PROBLEMA}}}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bf{\arabic {enumi}}.}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\hspace*{+4cm}\fbox{\textbf{ Gráfica de funciones}}
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}

\item primera gráfica

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymax=2]
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[color=red]{2*x**2/(x**2+1)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\item segunda gráfica

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymax=2]
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[color=red]{x**2+1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

When I compile I get these messages:

```
Plot data file `graficas.tkzfonct.table` not found.
Plot data file `graficas.tkzfonct.table` not found.
```

and I only get the Cartesian plane and no graph.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for providing a minimal document. Since the language of the site is English, could you translate the Spanish bits for us? I have no problems compiling your code (TL 2019 on a Mac). You can format code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon.

Comment: Saludos! If I recall correctly, you have to have `gnuplot` in your path and probably call with shell escape enabled. Also, it's worth mentioning that `tkz-fct` is currently unavailable in CTAN (and thus TL2020). Perhaps Alain is working on it.

Comment: I use the texmaker editor the latest version of 2020 on windows 10

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, excuse my ignorance but I did not understand about the texmf-cnf, as it would be in TexMaker

Comment: Apart from the observation that `tkz-fct.sty` seems to be no longer part of TeXLive2020, there are two things that could be important here: (1) use `-shell-escape`, as @PauloCereda is suggesting. (2) add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` as you are using `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`. I would not want to rule out that (1) helps just because it is not needed on some installations, if I remember correctly it was required with some older installations.

Comment: Don’t worry about texmf.cnf. I’ll delete my comments. This was a side discussion. @Schrödinger'scat can delete their comments about it too.

Comment: Yes tkz-fct is out of TL. I updated yesterday the package and It will be on CTAN in some hours. I think it will be possible to load it with Tex Live Utility in a few days. I think the problem appears because gnuplot is not found. If you want the new version and the new doc:  http://altermundus.fr/includes/fichiers.php

Comment: No problem to compile your example with TL 2020 but you need to use `-shell-escape`

Comment: Since this is an English speaking community, can someone please translate the question?